# Safely convert 2 bytes to short

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, byte, short

I'm making an emulator for the Intel 8080. One of the opcodes requires a 16 bit address by combining the `b` and `c` registers (both 1 byte). I have a struct with the registers adjacent to each other. The way I combine the two registers is:

```
using byte = char;

struct {

    ... code
    byte b;
    byte c;
    ... code

} state;

...somewhere in code    

// memory is an array of byte with a size of 65535
memory[*reinterpret_cast<short*>(&state.b)]
```

I was thinking I can just `OR` them together, but that doesn't work.

```
short address = state.b | state.c
```

Another way I tried doing this was by creating a short, and setting the 2 bytes individually.

```
short address;
*reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&address) = state.b;
*(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&address) + 1) = state.c;
```

Is there a better/safer way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
short j;
j = state.b;
j <<= 8;
j |= state.c;
```

Reverse the `state.b` and `state.c` if you need the opposite endianness.

Comment: This may cause undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M How so? You mean because the `short` is signed?

Answer (score 2):

```
short address = ((unsigned short)state.b << 8) | (unsigned char)state.c;
```

That's the portable way. Your way, with `reinterpret_cast` is not really that terrible, as long as you understand that it'll only work on architecture with the correct endian-ness.

Comment: The alignment problems are more serious than the endian-ness problems.

Comment: Well, the `short` will be appropriately aligned, so I don't see the issue there.

Comment: I'm responding to your last sentence, which is like saying it's okay to cross the street without looking both ways because you're very unlikely to get hit by an airplane. You've pointed him at a minor issue while ignoring a major one.

Comment: The reinterpret_cast<short *> way is UB due to violating the strict aliasing rule

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned there are concerns with endian-ness but you can also use a union to manipulate the memory without the need to do any shifting.

#### Example Code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using byte = std::uint8_t;

struct Regs
{
    union
    {
        std::uint16_t bc;

        struct
        {
            // The order of these bytes matters
            byte c;
            byte b;
        };
    };
};

int main()
{
    Regs regs;

    regs.b = 1; // 0000 0001
    regs.c = 7; // 0000 0111

    // Read these vertically to know the value associated with each bit
    //
    //                             2 1
    //                             5 2631
    //                             6 8426 8421
    //
    // The overall binary: 0000 0001 0000 0111
    //
    // 256 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 263

    std::cout << regs.bc << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
263
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/YduD5s)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
unsigned short address = state.b * 0x100u + state.c;
```

Using multiplication instead of shift avoids all the issues relating to shifting the sign bit etc.

The `address` should be `unsigned` otherwise you will cause out-of-range assignment, and probably you want to use 0 to 65535 as your address range anyway, instead of -32768 to 32767.