# Safely converting a non-owning pointer of multiple uint8_t's to uint16_t's

Tags: c++, serialization, c++20, endianness, uint16

I am getting data from a serial wire, thus the received data is an array of bytes (uint8_t). but these bytes are essentially a lot of two byte words (uint16_t). I am wondering what the best practice is to *safely* viewing a single pair of bytes or multiple pairs as uint16_t's without copying the data. The received data is in the format `[Word_1_LSB, Word_1_MSB, ..., Word_N_LSB, Word_N_MSB]` to account for the little endian architecture of where my code needs to run.

The received data is stored in a static `uint8_t` buffer and then `std::span` is used to hand out parts of the buffer as needed.

To avoid always `memcpy`-ing the data around, which would require additional buffers, or performing manual bit calculations, as discussed in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176021/safely-convert-2-bytes-to-short), is it somehow be possible to go from `std::span<uint8_t, size>` to `std::span<uint16_t, size/2>` or are there alignment problems? This would also be desirable for span's with dynamic extent.

Another idea was to use `reinterpret_cast`, as the data is laid out correctly for the endianness.

Finally I considered using a union to "reinterpret" the values with the below union, but I don't see how to convert multiple values at once this way.

```
union TwoBytes {
    uint8_t bytes[2];
    uint16_t combined;
};
```

What is the best practice to do so, using up to C++20?

Comment: Use of union or reinterpet_cast i C++ leads to UB. It will work on many compilers, but can stop working at any time. Proper way is to do prosper calculation `bytes[0] + bytes[1] << 8u` and let optimizer do its magic.

Comment: It's not shown in the dupe target but if you have an array of 8 bit integers and want to make that into an array of 16 bit integers you can `memcpy` they 8 bit array into the 16 bit array.